# Is there any way to make this code into 3 distinct classes?

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist

everyone, I finished doing the code for my lab, but I realized it has to have 3 classes named: Card, Deck, and DeckOfCards, it also preferably needs to have array lists, the thing is I am really not able to understand multiple classes and how to call things from another class. It would be great if anyone helps out. Right now I have just a single class named DeckOfCards which creates 3 arrays, and later combines them with a loop, shuffles them and prints the combined array

```java
public class DeckOfCards{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] s = {
            "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"
        };

        String[] face = {
        "1" ,"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
        "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
        };
        String[] ranks = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
        "10", "10", "10","10", "1 or 11"
        };
        int n = s.length * face.length;
        String[] deck = new String[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < face.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
                deck[s.length*i+j] = s[j] + ", " + face[i] + ", " + ranks[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (n-i));
            String temp = deck[r];
            deck[r] = deck[i];
            deck[i] = temp;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("["+deck[i]+"]");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The Deck of Cards class needs to print out the final shuffled array

Comment: You can edit your questions using the 'edit' button.

Comment: I'm sure there is.

Comment: Here you can see a similar idea: https://github.com/dperezcabrera/jpoker/tree/master/src/main/java/org/poker/api/core

Comment: Start by determining what properties each kind of object has.  Your existing code will help you with that.  For example, cards have a suit and rank.  They may also have a face value (but your code appears to confuse rank with face value).  A Deck presumably contains multiple cards.  I dunno what makes a `DeckOfCards` different from a `Deck`, but maybe it's intended for no other purpose than to serve as the program's main class.

Comment: *I am really not able to understand [...] how to call things from another class* - but **you're already doing it**.  What do you think `System.out.println()` or `Math.random()` or `face.length` does?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
enum Suit {
    Clubs,
    Diamonds,
    Hearts,
    Spades;
}

enum Face {
    Ace(1,11),
    Two(2),
    Three(3),
    Four(4),
    Five(5),
    Six(6),
    Seven(7),
    Eight(8),
    Nine(9),
    Ten(10),
    Jack(10),
    Queen(11),
    King(12);
    private final int rank;
    private final int alternativeRank;

    private Face(int rank, int alternativeRank) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.alternativeRank = alternativeRank;
    }

    private Face(int rank) {
        // Default to 0 for alternative rank.
        this(rank,0);
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public int getAlternativeRank() {
        return alternativeRank;
    }

}

class Card {
    private final Suit suit;
    private final Face face;

    public Card(Suit suit, Face face) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.face = face;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public Face getFace() {
        return face;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Card{" +
                "suit=" + suit +
                ", face=" + face +
                '}';
    }
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    // This should look familliar.
    Suit[] suits = Suit.values();
    Face[] faces = Face.values();
    Card[] deck = new Card[suits.length * faces.length];
    int c = 0;
    for ( Suit s : Suit.values()) {
        for (Face f : Face.values()) {
            deck[c++] = new Card(s,f);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
        int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (deck.length-i));
        Card temp = deck[r];
        deck[r] = deck[i];
        deck[i] = temp;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("["+deck[i]+"]");
    }
}
```

Comment: The constructors of `enum Face` should better be private.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch There was no need. Enum constructors are implicitly private.